# amTimeAgo with observable - constant refreshing every 1s

Tags: angular, momentjs, angular-moment, angular-pipe

Using

```
"angular2-moment": "^1.3.3",
"moment": "^2.18.1",
```

When I use the `amTimeAgo` pipe in template:

```
<div *ngFor="let issue of getIssues() | async ">
  {{ issue.time | amTimeAgo }}
  <!--{{ issue.time | amUtc }}-->
  <!--{{ issue.time | amLocal }}-->
  <p>{{ issue.time | amDateFormat:'dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a' }}</p>
  {{ issue.time }}
  {{issue | json }}
</div>
```

, with observable:

```
getIssues(): Observable<any[]> {

  return Observable.of([
    {
      name: "1",
      time: new Date(),
    },
    {
      name: "2",
      time: new Date(),
    },
    {
      name: "2",
      time: new Date(),
    }
  ]);
}
```

The constants are refreshed every second (new new Date() every time).

**How to prevent this?**

**Why is it getting new data every time?**

I don't want new data every time. Plus, this will be an HTTP call, thus expensive.

I guess change detection is triggered too often...

Other pipes I checked seem to not cause the problem (e.g. amDateFormat)

Comment: `I guess change detection is triggered too often...` this is correct. There are many things that trigger change detection cycle. You may be very surprised about how frequently it is triggered, in fact.

Comment: I think the change detection is triggered by the `amTimeAgo` pipe.

Comment: It is very possible. I hope you can configure the interval of the event then, because frequent events may affect performance of the entire component. Especially, if you have computationally heavy page...

Answer (score 3):

Your `getIssues()` method creates a new `Observable` every time it's called. The method is called whenever there is some reason for Angular to perform change detection. You probably have some source of events (maybe some timer or mouse event handler) that triggers the change detection so the time values get refreshed. You can create a simple page with just the code you posted and a button (and a click handler) - when you click the button, the times get refreshed.

So the only thing necessary is to assign the observable to a local property.

The `async` pipe calls `ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck()` which tells the Angular's change detection that there may be a change in this component. For more details see the following articles:

- https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html
- https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2017/02/27/three-things-you-didnt-know-about-the-async-pipe.html

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a snapshot of the moment on Init step of the component lifecycle and then reuse it in multiple results (assuming no code will mutate the date object afterwards)?

```
currentDate: Date;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.currentDate = new Date();
}

getIssues(): Observable<any[]> {
  return Observable.of([
    {
      name: "1",
      time: this.currentDate,
    },
    {
      name: "2",
      time: this.currentDate,
    },
    {
      name: "2",
      time: this.currentDate,
    }
  ]);
}
```

It's important to use `ngOnInit` here instead of a constructor.